# Is the sentence grammatically correct?

Tags: questions, negation, reported-speech

On page 10 of book *The 21 Day Happiness Challenge*, the second paragraph is

> "A good question to ask is, why do feel like you don't deserve
>   happiness?".

Is the sentence correct?

Comment: What do you think is wrong with the this text?

Comment: @JavaLatte I think there should have a pronoun 'you' after do.

Comment: My guess is that this sentences is one of those with a "do"+verb statements. Similar to: Why do make people like you when you can just ignore them? Or: This does happen whether you want it to or not! Although with your sentences a " do" statement sounds odd.

Comment: @SovereignSun, do you have references for your examples? Your first example sounds very wrong to me. The second example is OK, but it's nothing like the OP's sentence at all.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a typesetting error.

Answer (score 1):

This sentence is almost correct. I wonder if you maybe forgot a word when you copied the sentence from the text. It should read

> A good question to ask is, why do ***you*** feel like you don't deserve happiness?

Comment: There is no 'you' in the text

Comment: I don't see a mistake even without the extra 'you'.